# Redirecting if logging in from the home page with WP-Members

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a Wordpress site setup with the WP-Members plugin. It has a filter hook to redirect people to a specific page after login.

I have used this before but what I want to do is redirect them to this page only if they log in from the homepage.

I think I am almost there but it is not working.
Here is what I have :

```
add_filter( 'wpmem_login_redirect', 'my_login_redirect' );

function my_login_redirect( $redirect_to, $user_id ) {

    if ( is_front_page() ) {

        return '/dashboard/';

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
add_filter( 'wpmem_login_redirect', 'my_login_redirect', 999 );


function my_login_redirect( $redirect_to, $user_id ) {
    $ref = (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : '';
    if (!empty($ref)) {
        $path = parse_url($ref, PHP_URL_PATH);

        // check if the path from the URL is '/' or empty indicating home page
        // you may also want/need to check for /home, /index, /index.php etc.
        if ( null === $path || '/' == $path || '' == $path ) {
            return '/dashboard/';
        }
    }

    // where to redirect to if the login wasn't from the home page
    return '/members'; // <-- you probably want to change this
}
```

The 999 makes sure your filter runs after theirs to override the return. Specifcally this code checks the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` variable which contains the referring page.  Checking `is_front_page()` will not work because the logins happen from a different URL so this will never be the case.

Comment: Thank you this has kind of worked. If logging in from the home page it does forward to /dashboard/ as I am trying to achieve.

But if you log in from any other page when you log in the page goes blank.

Comment: @user1837290 I just updated the answer to add a default return value.  Since the function would return `null` if the login wasn't from the homepage, it appears the function must return some value.  Replace `/members` in the updated answer with the URL you want them to redirect to if it *wasn't* from the home page.

Comment: Thank you again. Do you happen to know if instead of using a default return value it can redirect to the current page?

Some pages have content on that you have to log in to see. So they have login forms on too. By default WP-Members displays a login form on them, you login, the page refreshes and shows the hidden content. But their filter hook seems to mess with that.

Comment: You could check the value of `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` and redirect to that if it was present and from your site's URL.  `$_POST['redirect_to']` might also be present indicating the URL wordpress was set to redirect to based on where the login was present.  the WP-Members plugin may have its own hidden redirect field but I am not familiar with that plugin so I'm not sure.

Comment: You were correct, WP-Members does have its own redirect field. You can just pass it the $redirect_to variable for a default value.